# Installing Open VMware Tools on different Ubuntu versions

Tags: vmware-esxi, vmware-vsphere, vmware-vcenter, vmtools

I have a range of Ubuntu servers dating back to v18.04.
Each one has a different version of Open VM Tools available through its' repository.
Is there anything that's preventing me from compiling and installing the latest one which is 12.3 from the official git repo?